# Gzip the files in unix

Tags: unix, gzip, ksh

I have a file called `Apple_PC.csv`
I need to gzip it such that the file name would be: `Apple_PC_<yyyymmddhhmmss>.gz`
But when it is unzipped it should have original file : `Apple_PC.csv`

Tried this:

```
   gzip -q  /users/files/Apple_PC_$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).gzip /users/files/Apple_PC.csv
```

It gives me error

```
gzip: Apple_PC_20171212105127.gzip: No such file or directory
```

I don't want my original file (Apple_PC.csv) in my directory available after successful gzip.
Not sure what am i missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compress it then move it.

```
gzip /users/files/Apple_PC.csv &&
    mv /users/files/Apple_PC.csv.gz \
       /users/files/Apple_PC_$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).gzip
```

I should add, gzip uses the filename of the compressed file to generate the name of the decompressed file, so you should act accordingly. You'll need to rename it going in and going out. `.gzip` will not work. This is probably what you need.

```
gzip /users/files/Apple_PC.csv && 
    mv /users/files/Apple_PC.csv.gz \
       /users/files/Apple_PC_$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).gz
# then to decompress
mv /users/files/Apple_PC_$(# match date here).gz \
   /users/files/Apple_PC.csv.gz &&
       gzip -d /users/files/Apple_PC.csv.gz
```

Alternatively, you could use stdin and stdout rather than moving files, but that may be another topic altogether.

There is also a `--name` option for preserving the original filename, but I am not sure how portable it is.

Comment: Was thinking of the same. I believed there would be something direct cmd.

Comment: See the edit. I added some detail for decompression and you might check out the `--name` option, but ymmv.

Comment: compress and move is remaining the original file and removing the extension .csv  as well. What if i don't have control of decompress.